# why I cannot load the pickle in a different module?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I created a pickle in module1 called `tabla_precios` and I am looking forward to open it in module2.
The pickle opens in a function in module1.

Currently I am importing the function in module2 , but I believe it is not the most efficient way because I think I am making the pickle each time I execute the module in the different module  ain't I?

Therefore I thought in importing the pickle directly in a different module but Im not sure on how to do it.

This is what i have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle

main_df=pd.DataFrame()

pickle_out=open ('tabla_precios.pickle','wb')
pickle.dump(main_df,pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

print(tabla_precios)
```

It comes the error:

```
name 'tabla_precios' is not defined
```

I am looking forward to import the pickle in a different module.

Comment: `print(tabla_precios)`: you don't have a `tabla_precios` variable defined, but you pass it to `print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pickle only stores references to classes and functions, not the functions themselves. If you pickle a class, the class definition needs to be in the namespace when you unpickle it. Modules in python are only imported once and then saved in `sys.modules`. Re-importing this module will not caused the code to be executed more than once. To test it, try adding a `print` statement in the module and see if it's called more than once.